# How to check, if '\n' on end CSV File

Tags: c++, csv, getline

I´ve got a CSV File with some data:

```
3;13.12.2014;inline;33;434;5434
```

How do I check if the line ends with '\n'?

I've tried use getline, but getline has got '\n' as delimiter.

Comment: Why exactly do you care?

Answer (score 3):

This is one case where checking for `eof()` would be in order.  The input for `std::getline` can be terminated by one of three conditions: end of file, a match for the terminator (which will be extracted) , or an attempt to extract more than `std::string::max_size()` characters.  In practice, the last condition will probably never occur; you'll have encountered an `std::bad_alloc` before then.  If the terminator has been extracted, then `eof()` will still be false, since the end of file will not have been seen.  If the input terminates because of end of file, then `eof()` will have been set; if no other characters have been input, then `std::failbit` will also have been set.  So the condition `eof() && !fail()` means that you've read the last line, and that it was missing the `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer.
So, I have construction:

```
fstream file("sport.csv", fstream::in);
string line;

while(getline(file,line))
{
    cout << line << endl;
}
```

And now, I don´t know, where I put the condition `eof() && !fail()` ?